# Convert a list of items to a list of item tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I want to add a new list til an old list which contains tuples. In a simple way something like this:

```
d = ['string', 1, 2, 3]
dlist = list(zip(d, d))
dlist2 = list(zip(dlist, d))
```

But this gives me:

```
[(('string', 'string'), 'string'), ((1, 1), 1), ((2, 2), 2), ((3, 3), 3)]
```

And I want:

```
[('string', 'string', 'string'), (1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3)]
```

What can I do?

Comment: Do you want to know how to go from `dlist`  to `dlist2`  or from `d`  to `dlist2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply call one more item in `zip`, for example:

```
d = ['string',1,2,3]
dlist2 = list(zip(d,d,d))
```

Will output exactly what you want...

But, if you actually wanted to move from `dlist` to `dlist2` and not straight from `d` to `dlist2` you can do exactly what you did, but just unpack it after, with `*`:

```
dlist = list(zip(d,d))
dlist2 = list(zip(dlist,d))
dlist2 = [(*item[0], item[1]) for item in dlist2]
```